# filter n number of times on an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I want to recreate filters that online shops have if someone wants to select says 'tshirts' and in 'green'. clearly that is easy. However, if they select multiple colours, how can I do this?

I know I can chain like this: `colors.filter(col => col.name =='green' || col.name =='black')`, but what if I wanted 10 colours selected or 20, this is currently not very scalable. Can I map over the colours in some way and then filter?

I tried this but it did not work:

```
colors = ['black', 'red']
col = [{name: 'green'}, {name: 'black'}, {name: 'red'}]
colors.forEach((c) => col.filter((ca) => ca.name === c))`
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If they select multiple colours, how can I do this?

You can use [`includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) or [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)  methods.

```js
colors = ['black', 'red']
col = [{name: 'green'}, {name: 'black'}, {name: 'red'}]
var selected = col.filter(prod => colors.includes(prod.name))
console.log(selected);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can just use a `Set`:

```
let filterColors = new Set();
filterColors.add('green');
filterColors.add('black');

colors.filter(col => filterColors.has(col.name));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new array for your final result called `selectedColor` so that objects are pushed with matching color.

```js
colors = ['black', 'red'];
col = [{name: 'green'}, {name: 'black'}, {name: 'red'}];
var selectedColor = [];
colors.forEach((c) => col.filter((ca) => {
   if(ca.name === c){
     selectedColor.push(ca);
   }
}));
console.log(selectedColor);
```

**USING indexOf()**

```js
colors = ['black', 'red']
col = [{name: 'green'}, {name: 'black'}, {name: 'red'}]
var selected = col.filter(prod => colors.indexOf(prod.name) !== -1)
console.log(selected);
```

> Using `indexOf()` is highly encouraged as `includes()` do not work in IE browsers.

Comment: `[1].indexOf(1)` returns `0`. Probably you wanted to check with `!== -1` instead.

Comment: @6502 yes, that was a typo. My bad. Thanks for the detection.

Answer (score 0):

You can use array.includes:

```js
colors = ['black', 'red']
cols = [{name: 'green'}, {name: 'black'}, {name: 'red'}];

var filtered = cols.filter(c => colors.includes(c.name));
console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
const colors = ['black', 'red']
const col = [{name: 'green'}, {name: 'black'}, {name: 'red'}]
let filtered = col.filter(ca => colors.includes(ca.name))
console.log(filtered)
```